# Rails Engines inheriting from a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines

Inside an app, is it possible to inherit from an engine's controller?

(eg: `class PersonController < EngineController`)

And have PersonController's views to default to the engine's, as usual in rails apps?

I'm not 100% sure if an engine is the right approach for me... since I'm not "mounting" anything here, more providing some default functionality to extend?

Comment: You can inherit the controller from an engine's controller. You should go for moving your main controller to rails engine only if you're planning to use that engine in some other application(basically reuse that controller somewhere else). But what do you mean by "since I'm not "mounting" anything here"?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, gives me hope :) By "not mounting" I mean  there is not routes in my engine. Just one very generic controller. And I wont mount the engine into any path in my app, only inherit from a controller and hopefully some default views. So no explicit route/path mounting. Wonder if this is why I'm getting "uninitialized constant EngineController" when I try to inherit inside my app?

Comment: Which type of engine you've created? Full or Mountable? You have to mount the engine path in routes, after mentioning it in your Gemfile(to make sure the classes defined in Engine are available to the application). Once you're done doing that. You can inherit Controllers of Engine in your application, the way you would want.